# Quarkus СacheManager injection in integration test

Tags: kotlin, caching, dependency-injection, integration-testing, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application that makes use of caches for methods.

These methods and cache eviction got to be tested somehow preferably when Quarkus context is fully operational.

This is what I figured ([PostgresContainer](https://pastebin.com/1YHw4jpC) for reference):

```
@QuarkusTest
class ScreeningRepositorySpec : PostgresContainer() {

    private val cacheManager = CaffeineCacheSupplier().get()

    init {
        "test cache manager gets initialized" {
            logger().info("Cache size: {}", cacheManager.size)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when any kind of invocation happens for `cacheManager`: it fires NPE. https://github.com/im-infamou5/quarkus-cache-playground

Downstream code as follows is

```
@Override
public List<CaffeineCache> get() {
    CacheManager cacheManager = cacheManager();
    ...
}
```

which ultimately yields:

```
public static CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return Arc.container().instance(CacheManager.class).get();
}
```

And here comes that `Arc.container()` is null somehow.

What else was tried:

- `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` - no bean for injection, null for arc container
- Explicit `@Inject` for `CacheManager` - yields "no bean matches injection point"
- Explicit `Cache` definition with manual `CacheManager` instantiation - same issue with null arc container
- Variations for `@Inject` for default bean injection - same things about missing injection point

Looks like `CacheManager` bean lifecycle issue that expects it way too early and never succeeds as a result.

I've dug into quarkus tests which have quite a [workaround](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/957ed4e84229cf0aafcb8a933edc236c394503f0/extensions/cache/deployment/src/test/java/io/quarkus/cache/test/runtime/CompletionStageReturnTypeTest.java#L31-L32) but still hope easier approach is available to avoid this much dependensies just to test cache properly.

Version of Quarkus is `2.7.0`.

Sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/im-infamou5/quarkus-cache-playground) with simple type of direct injection.

Output as follows:

```
org.acme.GreetingResourceIT > test cache size FAILED
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException at GreetingResourceIT.kt:11
        Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException at GreetingResourceIT.kt:11
```

Comment: Have you tried `@Inject CacheManager cacheManager`?

Comment: @geoand yes, it fails with no bean found, see "what else was tried" section

Comment: Do you have a sample I can try?

Comment: sure thing, i've updated question with sample project link. 
don't forget to amend needed artifactory settings in `settings.gradle.kts`

Comment: So the problem is in `GreetingResourceIT`, correct?

Comment: exactly, this file

Comment: `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` cannot access CDI beans - these are actually running in a different process altogether

Comment: alright, so can you please elaborate on how should cache be tested in runtime then?

Comment: `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` is a black-box test, it knows nothing about how the application is implemented - it can only intereact with it over the network, so it's not suitable for testing such things

Comment: hmm, but same thing works for Spring just fine. why it's not possible with quarkus?

Comment: Spring does **not** have an analogous of `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`. Spring's test are more like `@QuarkusTest`

Comment: Either way I have this feature for spring regardless of name and quarkus lacks it imo

Comment: As I said, you can do this with `@QuarkusTest`.

Comment: I've tried it and it works exactly the same way as the integration test for this case

Comment: It does not, If it's not working, there is something wrong with it's use.

Comment: perhaps you can point out exact approach that is currently working?
it is not set up this way even in quarkus itself (see link in `workaround`)